# How to see folders and files from RAID file system through Ubuntu?

Tags: data-recovery, raid

I have an old hard drive which RAID file system which i want to recover see the files and folder in it with the help of Ubuntu.

I am beginner in Linux. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There are many howtos available that adresses your question.

I assume that you've been using software raid. In such case you should read about `mdadm`.

If your raid has been auto-mounted you'll see your raid partitions in `/proc/mdstat`:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

It should be something like `/dev/md0`

Then you can simply mount it with:

```
sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt
```

An view your files in `/mnt`.

**If you don't have any other RAID devices currently used** you can scan your drives and assemble it:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

In other cases it's better to first check wchid device is your old raid and assemble it manually via `mdadm --create`.

You can see examples of `mdadm` command at:

- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/mdadm.8.html#examples

There is also wiki at kernel.org available:

- https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/A_guide_to_mdadm#Cookbook